# Why is <string>.format giving me this weird output in my inherited class object? (New to python)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a toString() method in an inherited class but it is giving me weird output and I don't know why. New to Python, please help.

This is part of the tutorial Python Programming: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4mEzFDjqtA&feature=youtu.be at minute 39. I tried changing the syntax a bit but the problem remained. Also, it didn't work with a direct call to the variables, as it is done in the video, but I had to use the get methods instead. Not sure why it works for him but not for me.

```
class Animal:
    __name = ""
    __height = 0
    __weight = 0
    __sound = 0

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__height = height
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__sound = sound

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def get_height(self):
        return self.__height
    def get_weight(self):
        return self.__weight
    def get_sound(self):
        return self.__sound

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and says {}".format(self.__name, self.__height, self.__weight, self.__sound)

class Dog(Animal):
    __owner = ""

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
        self.__owner = owner
        Animal.__init__(self, name,height,weight,sound)

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and says {}. His owner is {}".format(self.get_name, self.get_height, self.get_weight, self.get_sound, self.__owner)


cat = Animal('Whiskers', 33, 10, 'Meow')
print(cat.toString())
dog = Dog('Dida', 33, 10, 'Waf', 'Joshua')
print(dog.toString())
```

This gives me a result with things like: <**main**.Dog object at 0x00000243E9870390>> instead of the variables for the dog.toString() output. Instead of the actual variables.

Should be:
Whiskers is 33 cm tall and 10 kilograms and says Meow
Dida is 33 cm tall and 10 kilograms and says Meow. His owner is Joshua

Anyone can explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please make the effort to reproduce your indentation accurately if you're going to post Python code. If people have to guess your indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones.

Comment: if that's from an example in the tutorial, do yourself a favour and ditch the tutorial, it ain't worth a dime. This code is as totally unpythonic as it can be, what you're learning here is not Python but badly designed Java written in Python.

Comment: I second what Bruno is saying. Indeed, I left a comment on that video detailing exactly why it is a terrible Python tutorial

Comment: @khelwood Thank you for the feedback. But, what lines of code did I indent wrong? I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @bruno I did change the code a bit so maybe the fault is mine and not the tutorial's.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You could be right though.

Comment: Read the comment I left on that video. My screen name is basically the same.

Comment: @SamsonDaniel See the edit that someone made to your question.

Comment: @SamsonDaniel I confirm that this tutorial (at least the part on classes) is really really bad.

Comment: @khelwood I see now, thank you. I will watch my indentation in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mix of direct property access and methods, which are function. You can access properties directly like: `self.__weight` but you need to *call* the methods: `self.get_name()` (with `()`) otherwise you just print the string representation of the function itself.

A string method more like this should work better:

```
def toString(self):
    return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and says {}. His owner is {}".format(self.get_name(), self.get_height(), self.get_weight(), self.get_sound(), self.__owner)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark Meyer

Comment: @The_Flin I am using the Spyder environment and Python 3.7.0. It appears I can't answer your comment directly so that's why I am answering it here.